# Using sets and overloading operators in C++

Tags: c++

So for class this week I have to use a `set` to read in the Declaration of Independence and the US Constitution from a `.txt` file, store them in sets, and overload `operator*` to find and return the intersection of the two `set`s.

Reading everything in is not a problem, neither is finding out the intersection in the sets. What I'm having a lot of trouble with is overloading `operator*`. I keep getting two errors:

`no operator "*" matches these operands`
and

`binary "*":'std::set<_Kty>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`

Here is my code so far:

From main:

```
Reader r;
std::set<std::string> d, c;
d = r.GetDeclaraton();
c = r.GetConstitution();
Set dec(d), con(c);
Set intersection = dec * con;
```

The errors are coming from that last line of `main`.

From Set.h

```
class Set
{   
public:
    std::set<std::string> s;
    Set(void);
    Set(std::set<std::string> set)
    {
        s = set;
    }
    ~Set(void);
    std::set<std::string> operator* (const std::set<std::string> &rhs)
    {
        std::set<std::string> newset;
        std::set<std::string>::iterator rhsiter = rhs.begin(), result;
        while (rhsiter != rhs.end())
        {
            result = s.find(*rhsiter++);
            if (result != rhs.end())
            {
                newset.insert(*result);
            }
        }
        return newset;
    }
};
```

Comment: @TonyD I edited it because I had been using it differently before I posted, but still no luck.

Comment: @user3280133 - you do know that there is a std::set_intersection function, right?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/  Your operator* can be written in 2 lines if you use the algorithm functions

Comment: usage - `#include <iterator>` `set<std::string> newset;' 'set_intersection(s.begin(), s.end(), rhs.bgin(), rhs.end(), std::inserter(newset.begin()));`  `return newset;`  So I was wrong -- not 2 lines, 1 line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
Set operator* (const Set &rhs) const
```

because this is a binary operator with two `Set`s as arguments. Your attempt would only work if your `Set` was deriving `std::set`.

The return type here is `Set`. It makes more sense to be the same as the input arguments, and this is also consistent with your usage in `main`. So in this case you need to modify the definition to construct and return a `Set` instead of an `std::set` (or rather you need not because an `std::set` can be implicitly converted to a `Set`).

Note also I made `operator*` a `const` member function, since it's not modifying its object.

Comment: Ok so I changed everything so that it makes logical sense like you corrected me on, but now I'm getting an `unresolved external` error from `main`. I `#include`d `Set.h` `<set>` and `Reader.h`, what am I missing?

Comment: What's the name of the external?

Comment: @ivar `unresolved external symbol "public: _thiscall Set::~Set(void): (??1Set@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function_wmain`

Comment: That's because you declared `~Set(void);` and did not define it anywhere. You don't need it, just remove it.

Comment: Also you can replace `Set(void);` with `Set() = default;`.

Comment: Sweet! Now I just have to figure out my bugs, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`operator*` is defined in your custom `Set` so the left-hand-side argument must be a `Set`, but in `dec.s * con.s` you're using `.s` which accesses the member `std::set` fields, and there's no `operator*` defined for a left-hand `Set` and rhs-hand `std::set`.

You could change to `dec * con.s`, but it'd be better to change the `operator*` rhs argument to a `const Set&` too, and use `rhs.s` inside the operator... less confusing!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion its better to write a global or friend operator. Also, for intersection I would use the `&` operator, for union the `|` or `+` operator while, difference: `-`...

Why global operators? With global operators you can write an operator for your class even if the left operand is not your class. For example in case of a matrix class you can easily write a global operator that multiplies together a float and a matrix while as a matrix member operator you could write only an operator where your matrix is on the left.

Example:

```
template <typename T>
inline std::set<T> intersection(const std::set<T>& smaller, const std::set<T>& larger)
{
    std::set<T> result;
    for (auto it=smaller.begin(),eit=smaller.end(); it!=eit; ++it)
    {
        if (larger.find(*it) != larger.end())
            result.insert(*it);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
inline std::set<T> operator & (const std::set<T>& a, const std::set<T>& b)
{
    if (a.size() < b.size())
        return intersection(a, b);
    return intersection(b, a);
}

class Set
{   
public:
    std::set<std::string> s;
    Set() {}
    Set(std::set<std::string> _s) : s(_s) {}

    friend Set operator & (const Set& a, const Set& b)
    {
        return Set(a.s & b.s);
    }
};

int test()
{
    std::set<std::string> s, t;
    s.insert("aa");
    s.insert("bb");
    t.insert("bb");
    t.insert("cc");
    std::set<std::string> u(s & t);

    Set ss(s), st(t);
    Set result(ss & st);
    return 0;
}
```